# vue SyntaxError: Unexpected token (x:y) when using webpack-dev-server when using process.env variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

Building a Vue (2.7.14) component using webpack-dev-server and I'm trying make a url in my Vue CLI 2 code dynamic [via a process.env variable](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/vuejs-working-with-environment-variables#step-2-using-env-files-with-vue-cli-2). I've modified MyComponent.vue by changing this line of code in `MyComponent.vue`:

```
      const uploadUrl = `http://localhost:3000/api/mycall`;
```

to this:

```
      const uploadUrl = `${process.env.VUE_APP_APIURL}/api/mycall`;
```

(Rant/Aside: This problem original manifested as the webpack not getting updated. Since I was setting the process.env variable to the same value as I was using in the hard-coded version, I actually thought it was working until much later. However, what you SHOULD see is the actual text change - in my case `${process.env.VUE_APP_APIURL}` - in the browser code. Only after a bit of investigation did I realize that webpack-dev-server was hiding the build problem by clearing the error from the screen. After figuring out that the webpack wasn't getting updated I finally thought to scroll upward in my terminal - which was displaying a 'DONE Compiled successfully message.' [Maybe related to this.](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/12090) Gah!)

After making the change above I start getting these webpack compilation errors.

```
15% building modules 49/58 modules 9 active .../src/components/MyComponent.vue
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:5)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/darrin/src/applet/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2488:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/darrin/src/applet/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:623:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (/Users/darrin/src/applet/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:617:26)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/Users/darrin/src/applet/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2043:38)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (/Users/darrin/src/applet/node_modules/acorn-dynamic-import/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:1978:41)
```

Here's the conf for `dev.env.js` where the variable value is defined:

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  VUE_APP_APIURL: 'http://localhost:3001'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that this was because I forgot the inner quotes in the variable values. Looking again more closely at the example and then finding some documentation that says that [variables need to be wrapped into single and double quotes. e.g. '"foo"', but never 'foo'](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html)... the fix is simple:

```
'use strict'
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const prodEnv = require('./prod.env')

module.exports = merge(prodEnv, {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  VUE_APP_APIURL: '"http://localhost:3001"'
})
```

For anyone reading this not able to see the difference (as was the case for my autocorrecting mind) - let me narrow this - we're talking about going from this string:

```
  VUE_APP_APIURL: 'http://localhost:3001'
```

To this ([the double quotes inside the single quotes are required](https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html)) one:

```
  VUE_APP_APIURL: '"http://localhost:3001"'
```

Hopefully this helped someone. If you stumbled across this and are feeling frustrated, angry or ashamed, you've got company from me and [this guy](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4243). Super frustrating.